# get all combinations of this classical ball-box application

Tags: combinations

I don't know if there is a name for this problem, but it is: there are 10 balls (numbered `1,2,3...10`) and 3 boxes(named `A,B,C`). We want to find put the balls into any of the three boxes. I want to get all the possible combinations `{(ball1,box A),(ball2,box A),(ball3, box B)...}`, `{(ball1,box B),(ball2,box A),(ball3, box B)...}`, `{(ball1,box C),(ball2,box B),(ball3, box B)...}`... How to program to find all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be 3^10 combinations, since there is no limitation on the number of balls in the box. 
The most straight forward idea is to recursively computing the. a simple sudo code is as follows:

```
void Function(int Number_balls, int combs[10])
{
    if(Number_balls == 10)
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
           printf("%d \t ", combs[i])
    else{
        combs[Number_balls] = 1;
        Function(Number_balls++ , combs[10]);
        combs[Number_balls] = 2;
        Function(Number_balls++ , combs[10]);
        combs[Number_balls] = 3;
        Function(Number_balls++ , combs[10]);}
} 
int main()
{
    int combs[10];
    int Number_balls=0;
    combs[Number_balls] = 1;
    Function(Number_balls++ , combs[10]);
    combs[Number_balls] = 2;
    Function(Number_balls++ , combs[10]);
    combs[Number_balls] = 3;
    Function(Number_balls++ , combs[10]);

}
```